# Каким образом возможнf отправки списка контрагентов най сайт PHP?

Tags: 1с

Интересует возможность доработки раздела обмена сайтом на 1сУТ, а именно формирование и отправка контрагентов в формате xml/json на сайт PHP (сайт самописный)

Comment: Вы можете из 1С выполнить HTTP запрос к вашему сайту. Ваш сайт, в свою очередь, должен обработать входящий запрос